# How to overload extension methods in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I created small c++/cli dll that contains the following code:

```
[ExtensionAttribute]
public ref class PointExtension abstract sealed
{
public:
    [ExtensionAttribute]
    static int **ToMyInt**(System::Windows::Point^ point)
    {
        return 2222;
    }
};

[ExtensionAttribute]
public ref class VectorExtension abstract sealed
{
public:
    [ExtensionAttribute]
    static int **ToMyInt**(System::Windows::Vector^ vector)
    {
        return 2222;
    }
};
```

This code has two methods with the same name and the compilation process is going well.

But when I want to use my dll in C# code there is a problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)

{

    Point p1 = new Point(1, 2);
    Vector v1 = new Vector(3, 4);

    int I1 = v1.ToMyInt();
    int I2 = p1.ToMyInt();
}
```

Here the compiler says that ToMyInt are ambiguous.
But there is no problem to implement two extension methods with the same name directly in c# code using word "this".

Comment: Point and Vector are value types, *struct* in C# speak.  And therefore must be written without the ^ hat.  It is ambiguous because this syntax requires the caller to box the value to turn it into a ^ reference, the actual argument type in the code emitted by the compiler is System::ValueType.  Delete the ^ to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much.